# How to connect different outputs from one LiPo battery?

Tags: electronics

I am building a robot. I am going to use ONBO 6S 22000 mAh 25C to power all my controller boards and motors. It needs to power the following items:

1. 1 motor driver (24 V, 6 A);
2. Microcontroller board (5 V, 6 A);
3. Vacuum Motor (12 V, 20 A).

Is there any power distribution board which can output different voltages from one battery source?

Answer (score 0):

To step down voltages you can use one of these two commonly available electronic components:

1. Voltage regulator IC : These ICs regulate fixed voltages at their output terminals given the fact that the input terminals have voltages in a fixed range (higher than output voltage). For e.g. IC 7805 maintains a constant 5V for inputs ranging from 7-35V. More details: https://electronicsforu.com/resources/learn-electronics/7805-ic-voltage-regulator
2. Buck converter: This is a power electronic DC-DC converter. Converts inputs voltages within input range to variable output voltages that can be changed with the help of a potentiometer provided. Look out for LM2596 buck converters.

Both of these are mostly available on online shops, even Amazon. Please check out the current rating of components before buying if it satisfies your load demand.

Comment: Voltage regulators are terrible - they convert excess voltage to heat which is wasteful and you also have to dissipate that heat with heat sinks.

Comment: Buck converters convert a dc voltage to a higher dc voltage. Switchmode converters convert a dc voltage to a lower dc voltage with around 95% efficiency.